# Access control lists and permission on directory

Tags: files, permissions, acl

So I have a script infinite.sh that is in the /root directory.

I want to give the user Bob permission to run this script.

So what I did is that

```
setfacl -m u:Bob:rwx infinite.sh
```

and

```
setfacl -m d:Bob:rwx /root
```

However, when I switch to the user Bob, I still can't even cd into the /root directory of run the infinite script -- that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
setfacl -m d:Bob:rwx /root
```

will set a "default" for new directories created inside `/root` but doesn't change that directory itself.

You may have meant

```
setfacl -m u:Bob:rwx /root
```

Note that this is insecure; Bob can now modify files (eg `mv .profile .profile.old` and create a new `.profile`) to gain full root access.

Better might be

```
setfacl -m d:Bob:rx /root
```

so Bob can *read* stuff but not change it.

Similarly:

```
setfacl -m u:Bob:rx infinite.sh
```